# How do I place a heredoc at the end of a Bash sftp connection attempt?

Tags: bash, sftp

Trying to get this snippet working properly. I want to attempt an `SFTP` connection 3 times before breaking and exiting the shell. The catch is that there's a heredoc and `sftp` is not taking the heredoc as input when the connection is successful; the shell becomes interactive which I don't want.

```
count=0; until sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $key $server ; do ((count++)); [[ $count -eq 3 ]] && echo $count && break && exit 64; done; <<END
get docs/*
quit
END
```

Comment: heredoc is just another way of sending input to stdin, but it has to be sent to something that's listening. You're not sending it to `sftp`. Try looking at the `-b` option to `sftp`.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest using `lftp` (which, yes, supports the sftp protocol) rather than the `sftp` tool; don't even need a heredoc there, and there's native support for directory mirroring &c.

Comment: Also, you've got some bash syntax errors; see http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: ...and there's no good reason for the huge one-liner. Line breaks (and, when you need them, backslash continuations) are your friends.

Comment: @miken32 could you explain the `-b` option? You're the second person to recommend it, and I'm confused by the man page's description of it. It doesn't seem to apply to what I'm doing, but I also have no idea what it even is supposed to do...

Comment: @simplycoding It's a file containing your commands. See my answer below.

Comment: BTW, because of the `break`, the `exit 64` won't be executed.

Comment: Yep, I added that in for testing purposes. Thanks for the reminder though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't write this this way at all (consider `lftp` rather than `sftp`), but:

```
count=0
until sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "$key" "$server" <<END
get docs/*
quit
END
do
  if (( count++ >= 3 )); then echo "$count failures" >&2; exit 64; fi
END
```

Comment: Ah, I was putting in a `;` after the heredoc before the `do` line. Thanks

Comment: BTW, if you have questions about any of my other changes (ie. the change from using the short-circuiting `&&` to an `if` statement), feel free to ask; I have non-stylistic reasons for all of them.

Comment: Could you explain the `>&2` part? I'm actually trying to implement that in a `psql` connection attempt as well. Basically, I'm trying to output a bad `psql` connection attempt into a variable. If said variable equals something, then do something else.

Comment: The `>&2` part is simply putting something that's evidently for human consumption onto stderr (vs stdout, which is appropriate for content that's actual process output, ie. what you'd want to be in a pipeline for further processing).

Comment: re: scripting psql -- have you looked at whether exit status is sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: I have - isn't that (exit status) what's directed to stderr through `>&2`

Comment: No. Exit status is a numeric variable that ends up in `$?`, and determines which branch of `if somecommand; then : "exit status was 0"; else : "exit status was nonzero"; fi` is followed for `somecommand`. It's unrelated to stderr, which is (conventionally) the channel used for log messages intended to be read by a human.

Comment: ...so, `exit 64` is using an exit status of 64 -- which, being nonzero, is a failure. (By convention, 1 is the usual "generic failure" exit status, with 0 for success and other values being reserved for an application to define and document for its own uses).

Comment: Yep, from what I understand, you can use any number and it doesn't really matter. I just chose 64

Comment: If you're just making an arbitrary choice, use `1`; that way you're leaving higher bits available for use if you want to define and document an actual convention later.

Comment: ("any number" isn't quite right -- it's an 8-bit, unsigned value, so that's only 0-255; and I'd tend to suggest avoiding 127 or above without reason, as there are some occasionally-followed conventions around them).

Comment: I think you meant to put `done` instead of `END` at the end of your answer right?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure `commands.txt` contains your commands, one per line.

```
count=0
until sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "$key" -b commands.txt "$server"
do
    ((count++))
    [[ $count -eq 3 ]] && echo $count && exit 64
done
```

Comment: This copies a bug from the original: The `break` prevents the `exit 64` from being reached.

Comment: ...and another bug: If the `echo` fails, then this is skipping the `break` entirely.